# JSON object iteration not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to iterate over a json object using the following code but iteration is not working

```
function iterateRows()
{
    var timein_rows = [{"id":"72","date":"2012-08-01"},{"id":"73","date":"2012-08-01"}];
    $.each(timein_rows, function(i, item) {
       alert(item.id);
    });
}
```

I have crated json string using php `json_encode`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: works for me. http://jsfiddle.net/F9yMv/

Comment: Are you sure that's what `timein_rows` contains? Not a string?

Comment: You code just works. http://jsfiddle.net/FwFAq/

Answer (score 1):

In this fiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yFcdM/) it works fine.

Check:

- your code is calling `iterateRows()` where you are expecting it to be called from
- That the required jQuery library is included/referenced where your script is executed at

Based on the comment, if the above is fine, check the JSON values each time the call is executed, you could do similar to `console.log(timein_rows);` before `.each()`.

For example, doing that with the code you posted the console output looks similar to:

```
[Object { id="72",  date="2012-08-01"}, Object { id="73",  date="2012-08-01"}]
```

Check the JSON outputs between the working call and the not-working call for differences.

Comment: Jquery is working fine and this function is called in other part of my script

Comment: @Vinay: Is `var timein_rows` always the hard-coded values you are showing or is it set dynamically? If it is set dynamically, check if an invalid format/value is in the JSON and compare that JSON to the one where it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser's error console. It's most likely a JavaScript error in the version you are using.